# Python: how does a thread wait for other thread to end before resuming it's execution?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, sqlite, locking

I am making a bot for telegram, this bot will use a database (SQLite3).

I am familiar with threads and locks and I know that is safe to launch multiple thread that make query to the database.
My problem rises when I want to update/insert data.

With the use Condition and Event from the [threading module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html), I can prevent new thread to access the database while a thread is updating/inserting data.

What I haven't figured out is how to wait that all the thread that are accessing the database are done, before updating/inserting data.

If I could get the count of semaphore I would just wait for it to drop to 0, but since is not possible, what approach should I use?

UPDATE: I can't use join() since I am using [telegram bot](https://www.pornhub.com/view_video.php?viewkey=ph591d26ea22caf) and create thread dynamically with each request to my bot, therefore when a thread is created I don't know if I'll have to wait for it to end or not.

CLARIFICATION: join() can only be used if, at the start of a thread you know wether you'll have to wait for it to end or not. Since I create a thread for each request of my clients and I am unaware of what they'll ask or and when the request will be done, I can't know whether to use join() or not.

UPDATE2: Here the code regarding the locks. I haven't finished the code regarding the database since I am more concerned with the locks and it doesn't seems relevant to the question.

```
lock = threading.Lock()
evLock = threading.Event()

def addBehaviours(dispatcher):
    evLock.set()
    # (2) Fetch the list of events
    events_handler = CommandHandler('events', events)
    dispatcher.add_handler(events_handler)
    # (3) Add a new event
    addEvent_handler = CommandHandler('addEvent', addEvent)
    dispatcher.add_handler(addEvent_handler)

# (2) Fetch the list of events
@run_async
def events(bot, update):
    evLock.wait()
    # fetchEvents()

# (3) Add a new event
@run_async
def addEvent(bot, update):
    with lock:
        evLock.clear()
        # addEvent()
    evLock.set()
```

Comment: Could you show relevant parts of your code? It would help us a lot :D

Comment: My question is not tied to this specific case. I gave context just to be more precise. The problem is "how does a thread knows that other dynamically created threads are finished?"

Comment: Have you set a busy timeout for your database connections, and/or using the database in wal mode so readers don't block a writer? Actual code would be useful to see.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `threading.Thread.join()`. This will wait for a thread to end and only continue on when the thread is done.

Usage below:

```
import threading as thr
thread1 = thr.Thread()  # some thread to be waited for
thread1 = thr.Thread()  # something that runs after thread1 finishes
thread1.start()         # start up this thread
thread1.join()          # wait until this thread finishes
thread2.start()
...
```

Comment: I can't use join

Comment: Does it return an Exception? If so, show the exception here.

Comment: I can't literally used it since my threads are made dynamically